# Where can I find the assembly instructions of the chinese Ferrari Daytona gold/black variant?

Tags: technic, clone-brands, instructions

I bought on Aliexpress a Ferrari Daytona, 1:1 compatible with the original LEGO set, but it's the black/gold variant.

I didn't receive the book, as expected, but I was unaware that the set has no PDF either.

So I'm at the end of pack 3 of 7. The 4th box is where we start to build the front end of the car. I cannot continue to guess which red parts are now black and which are not gold.

Too difficult.

Do you know if a PDF is available somewhere for this variant?

If it doesn't exist, feel free to answer "no", I will upvote anyway.

Comment: Given that it’s a knockoff set using stolen intellectual property and made with minimal effort (as evidenced by the lack of instructions), I would highly doubt the existence of a recoloured instruction pdf

Comment: Ok, thanks for replying me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is my solution to the chinese clones:

- Step one is to sort the pieces by color
- Step two is to use [LEGO's official instructions site](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/42143) to download both high-quality books.
- Step three is to build using the instructions as if red and silver were replaced, so this means red pieces are black and the silver ones are gold.

(I haven't done this myself yet so this is just an idea)

EDIT: so this Chinese clone needs a refund to the Ali seller for the instructions supplied by a cloner (a cloner has more steps in same pages than LEGO was).

Comment: I undestand. I am now at end of book 3, where I built the front end, and It is now not so hard as I was supposing. Not relaxing, at all. but not hard. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Note that presumably not all pieces have been color-swapped. Most probably the Technic connectors and axles have retained their original color-coding (if the IP thieves were attentive enough to copy that as well).